# Opening all bookmarks with a given tag at once in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, bookmarks, tagging

I'd like to open all the similarly tagged bookmarks in Firefox at once.

Example use case: I have a few sites with regex tools bookmarked and when I need to write a regex, I usually open each one before I start working. Each of these sites is a Firefox bookmark and is tagged "regex". I would like to be able to type "regex" somewhere (search bar? address bar?) and have the option to click "open all tabs tagged "regex".

Is there a way to do this? Is there maybe an add-on that does that? Otherwise, if you have any tips, I could write the extension.

If you have the same problem, please let me know what features you would like in the comments to this question and I'll try to implement them if I do go that route.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer the part where you want some pointers to create an extension for this, the best place to start should be [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Places_Developer_Guide#Bookmarks).

If you don't want to go that route, you can always search for the tag you want, select all and "Open all in tags"

Comment: Thanks for the awesome resource. I'm using the "Open all in tabs" trick for now, but I think an extension would also raise awareness that it's possible to do this for the greater public, so I might still make the extension at some point when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way I've found so far to achieve this is: `Ctrl-B` (open bookmarks sidebar), type in tag, `right-click` in a blank area of the sidebar, select `Open all in tabs`